# (Bockstein Spectral Sequence) Why is $v_1$ also $p$-divisible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, spectral-sequences

[image]

Why if $u=pv_1$, then $v_1$ is also $p$-divisible?

I am quite puzzled by the above. I can see that $v_1$ must also generate a copy of $\mathbb{Z}$, thus $v_1\notin\ker p^r$. I can't seem to proceed to conclude further.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It's for the exact same reasons we concluded that $u\in p\cdot H_n(X)$. Recall that we are assuming that $B^{r+1}_n=0$, so we therefore have $H_n(X)=p\cdot H_n(X)+\ker(p^r)$. If $v_1\notin\ker(p^r)$ then $v_1\in p\cdot H_n(X)$.

Comment: @Tyrone Thanks. But can’t $v_1=a+b$, where $a\in pH_n(X)$, and $b\in\ker p^r$?

Comment: I think you're actually right here, so McCleary should have written that we can choose $v_1\in pH_n(X)$ such that $pv_1=u$.